# Reset div style after onDismiss Handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, popup

Looking for a solution to reset a div on a Modal after it is dismissed. The problem with my pop-up seems to come from the div that keeps the previous styling of display: none instead of going back to display: flex. I've been looking for a solution but I haven't been able to find one.  Any feedback would be appreciated!

My Code:

```
interface PopUpProps {
    message: any
  }

  
  const PopUpMessage: React.FC<PopUpProps> = ({message}) => {
    const TranslateString = useI18n()
    
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true)
    const onDismiss = () => {
        setVisible(false)
    }

    return (
         <div style={{display: visible? 'flex': 'none', position: 'absolute', zIndex: 10, top: '0px', left: '0px', width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
         <div style={{position: 'absolute', top: '10%', width: '30%', height: '30%'}}>
        <Modal title={`${TranslateString(999, 'Loot')}`} onDismiss={onDismiss}>
            <StyledVideo autoPlay playsInline controls={false} loop muted>
          <source src={message[1]} />
            </StyledVideo>
            <StyledText color="failure">{message[2]}!!!</StyledText>
        </Modal>
         </div>
         </ div>
    )
}

export default PopUpMessage
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

check to see if that onDismiss is actually changing state properly. Maybe it isn't getting the props properly too??
Try running it as a anonymous function:
`<Modal onMouseEnter={() => setVisible(!prev)}>...</Modal>;`
and console.logging the visible, and see what you get?

Comment: Hello! Yes, the state is changing for the so the pop up appears but after I exit out of the Modal the div stays at display: 'none'. Looking to see if there is a process that can reset the div after Dismissing the Modal.

Comment: Have you tried using useEffect? you could set the dependency array to the Modal, and whenever it changes its state, you can have it change the state of the div (reset the div).
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html